# Calculate frequency of occurrence in 2 different tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like:

```
table1
user 
_____
a
a
a
b
c
d
d
d
e
e
e
f
g
g
g
```

and

```
table2
user 
_____
a
b
c
d
e
e
f
g
g
g
```

I want to generate a third table with the frequency for each table, that looks like this:

```
n_users | count_t1 | count_t2
________|____________________
3       | 1        | 1         (b, c, f appear once in each table) 
2       | 3        | 1         (a, d appear 3 times in table1, once in table2
1       | 3        | 2         (e appears 3 times in table1, 2 in table2)
1       | 3        | 3         (g appears 3 times in both tables)
```

The idea is actually have count_t1 and count_t2 in a range, so say 1-10, 11-20, etc, so I' assuming I'll have to use FLOOR for that.
So far, I've come up with this

```
SELECT  COUNT(*), t1.countt1, t2.countt2 FROM (
       (SELECT user, COUNT(*) AS countt1 FROM table1 GROUP BY 1) t1) 
       JOIN 
       (SELECT user, COUNT(*) AS countt2 FROM table2 GROUP BY 1) t2) 
       USING(user))
       GROUP BY 2,3;
```

This is too inefficient and doesn't run on my machine. Also, the Mysql version is old, a version older than 8.

Comment: *So far, I've come up with this* Test on the data where some user is not present in some table.

Comment: *This is too inefficient* Your version does not allow to build more effective solution. Use pre-calculation (trigger). Create separate users table.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) n_users,
       count_t1,
       count_t2
FROM ( SELECT user, 
              COALESCE(table1.cnt, 0) count_t1, 
              COALESCE(table2.cnt, 0) count_t2
       FROM ( SELECT user FROM t1
              UNION 
              SELECT user FROM t2 ) users
       LEFT JOIN ( SELECT user, COUNT(*) cnt
                   FROM t1
                   GROUP BY user ) table1 USING (user)
       LEFT JOIN ( SELECT user, COUNT(*) cnt
                   FROM t2
                   GROUP BY user ) table2 USING (user) ) total
GROUP BY count_t1,
         count_t2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=02a3812885c8d6736015d562f96551b2

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*) n_users,
count_t1,
count_t2
FROM ( SELECT user,
COALESCE(table1.cnt, 0) count_t1,
COALESCE(table2.cnt, 0) count_t2
FROM ( SELECT user FROM t1
UNION
SELECT user FROM t2 ) users
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT user, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM t1
GROUP BY user ) table1 USING (user)
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT user, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM t2
GROUP BY user ) table2 USING (user) ) total
GROUP BY count_t1,
count_t2

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` and `group by` to get the counts within each table:

```
select user, sum(in1) as cnt1, sum(in2) as cnt2
from ((select user, 1 as in1, 0 as in2
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select user, 0, 1
       from table2
      )
     ) t
group by user;
```

Then aggregate again:

```
select cnt1, cnt2, count(*) as num_users
from (select user, sum(in1) as cnt1, sum(in2) as cnt2
      from ((select user, 1 as in1, 0 as in2
             from table1
            ) union all
            (select user, 0, 1
             from table2
            )
           ) t
      group by user
     ) u
group by cnt1, cnt2;
```